# MessageResource not loading resource message files ( or some other reason ) - Internationalization not working

Tags: spring-boot, internationalization, message

@RestController
@RequestMapping("repo")
public class SampleController {

```
@Autowired
MessageSource messageSource;

@GetMapping(value = "data-internationalised")
public User getAllUsersInt(@RequestHeader(name = "Accept-Language", required = false) Locale locale) {
    User user = User.builder().address("4461")
            .age(38)
            .name("Na")
            .message(messageSource.getMessage("good.morning.message", null, "Hello", locale))
            .build();
    System.out.println(">>1>>" + locale.getCountry());
    System.out.println(">>2>>>" + locale.getDisplayCountry());
    System.out.println(">>3>>>" + locale.getDisplayCountry(locale));
    System.out.println(">>4>>>" + locale.getLanguage());
    return user;
}
```

}

Three properties files are under src/main/resources
messages.properties
messages_fr.properties
messages_nl.properties

When I make a get request, I always get "Hello" and not the message per properties files.
Why is it not working. I am using spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
```

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver;

import java.util.Locale;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localResolver() {

    SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();

    localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);

    return localeResolver;

}


@Bean
public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {

    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource =

            new ResourceBundleMessageSource();

    messageSource.setBasename("messages");

    return messageSource;

}
```

Create an AppConfig class if its not there, or Add these two methods into it.